# Read access violation on Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, access-violation

I have a very simple linked list that I want to perform functions on, but I keep getting the read access violation error on the 'root' node when I run my code.

Here is the error I get (I commented after the lines of code I get the errors in):

*Exception thrown: read access violation.
root was 0xCCCCCCCC.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.*

This is the struct:

```
struct node {
int value;
node* link;

node(int val) {
    link = NULL;
    value = val;
}
};
```

First I initialize that linked list in main function like this:

```
int main() 
{
node *root;

addnode(root, 20);
addnode(root, 1);
addnode(root, 50);


node *curr;
for (curr = root; curr->link != NULL; curr = curr->link) { // I get error here
    cout << curr->value << " ";
}
cout << endl;

cout << "Number of elements " << countlist(root) << endl;

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

And the function that are called are (first one to add nodes, and the second to count the number of nodes in the list):

```
void addnode(node *&root, int val) {
if (root != NULL) { // I get error here
    node *temp=new node(val);
    temp->link = root;
    root = temp;
}
else
    root = new node(val);
}

int countlist(node *root) {
if (root != NULL) {
    int count = 0;

    do {
        count++;
        root = root->link;
    } while (root->link != NULL); // I get error here

    return count;
}
return 0;
}
```

The error I keep getting are in the lines that I mentioned in the comments in the code.

Comment: Say, `root == 0x12345` and `root->next == NULL` before the loop. What do you expect your condition to check?

Comment: `root` is not initialized but its (random, uninitialized) value is used.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you provide more info about reproducing this bug?

Comment: if `root->next==NULL` it'll go into loop, count 1 then become NULL and then its supposed to stop traversing and not give the error, but the root seems to still go to NULL and still not exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good habit to avoid this kind of problem might be initializing all variables at declaration:

```
int main() 
{
   node *root = nullptr;
   // ...
}
```

Also, you do not want:

```
node *curr;
for (curr = root; curr->link != NULL; curr = curr->link) {
    cout << curr->value << " ";
}
```

but

```
for (node *curr = root; curr != nullptr; curr = curr->link) {
    cout << curr->value << " ";
}
```

Comment: This worked, but the first element that I add in main `addnode(root,20)` does not show up when I print the list, and is not counted in the count function (it just disappears)

Comment: Add new question on SO with your current problem